# Linq get data from m to n tables?

Tags: c#, linq, relational-database

I have 2 Tables that is m to n relationships between them. Roles, Moduls, ModulsInRoles. I get current user roles. IAnd I want to get these roles' moduls. I tried to write something. But I cant success.

```
string[] roller = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();

IEnumerable<TblModuller> moduller = null;
IEnumerable<TblModulsInRoles> moduls_in_roles = null;

foreach (var rol in roller)
{
     moduls_in_roles = entity.TblModulsInRoles.Where(x => x.Roles.RoleName == rol);
     foreach(var modul in moduls_in_roles)
     {
         //I dont know What should I write or this code is correct.
     }
}
```

for example; My data is like this:

```
Admin  Modul1
Admin  Modul2
User   Modul2
User   Modul3
```

And I want to get this:

```
Modul1
Modul2
Modul3
```

What is the logic? and Is there some code example or tutorial about this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
var modullerList = new List< TblModuller>();

foreach (var rol in roller)
{
     moduls_in_roles = entity.TblModulsInRoles.Where(x => x.Roles.RoleName == rol);
     foreach(var modul in moduls_in_roles)
     {
        if(!modullerList .Contains(modul))
            modullerList .Add(modul);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I want to ask If Is there different way?

Comment: var modullerList = entity.TblModulsInRoles.Where(roller.Contains(x.Roles.RoleName));  This will also return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question *"I want to ask If Is there different way?"*: you could use `SelectMany`. I'm not sure I totally understand the structure of what you're working with, but I've guessed. Hopefully it's right.

```
string[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();

var modules = roles
    .SelectMany(r =>
        entity.TblModulsInRoles.Where(m => m.Roles.RoleName == r)
    )
    .Distinct();
```

Assuming each module returned from `TblModulesInRoles` is the same object referenced in each role mapping, this should work. If it's not the same object, then your module entity will probably have to be comparable by one of the standard ways.

Here's the code I used to test this locally. Obviously it's not entirely the same thing, but it demonstrates `SelectMany`, at least.

```
public class Module
{
    public Module(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

Module one = new Module("one");
Module two = new Module("two");
Module three = new Module("three");

Dictionary<string, List<Module>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Module>>
{
    {"cow", new List<Module> { one, two }},
    {"chicken", new List<Module> { one }},
    {"pig", new List<Module> { two }}
};

string[] roles = new string[] { "cow", "chicken", "pig" };

var result = roles.SelectMany(r => dict[r]).Distinct();

Console.WriteLine(result);

// { one, two }
```